# Cloning POI style from sheet to another

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have a template XSSF sheet
I am trying to create an SXSSF file based on the template, I could create the sheet successfully, but I have a problem when I am trying to copy the styles from old sheet to the new sheet

Here is my code

```
FileInputStream templateFile = null;
XSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = null;
XSSFSheet templateSheet = null;

templateFile = new FileInputStream(this.templateFilePath);
templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(templateFile);
templateSheet = templateWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

SXSSFWorkbook sworkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(this.largeReportCashRows);      
SXSSFSheet sworksheet = (SXSSFSheet) sworkbook.createSheet();


//Create styles
CellStyle newStyle = sworkbook.createCellStyle();
//style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.FINE_DOTS );
//style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
CellStyle oldCellStyle = templateSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle();
newStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCellStyle);

//SOME CODE TO CREATE ROWS & CELLS IN THE new sheet "sworksheet"
Cell cell1;
cell1.setCellStyle(newStyle);
```

When I execute the code, it runs and generates the sheet, but when I open it I am getting an error telling me that the sheet is corrupted, After telling Excel to fix it. It is fixed but the styles aren't working !

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
        //to get old cell style from a cell
        CellStyle oldCellStyle = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle();

        //to create a new sheet in which you want to use this style
        XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.createSheet("new2");

        row=sheet2.createRow(0);
        cell=row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("test");
        //to set old style to new cell
        cell.setCellStyle(oldCellStyle);

        FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out1);
        out1.close();
```